# Disable css class for specific browser

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jquery library which is not working correctly in Safari . Is there a way to disable css classes applied to an element for specific browsers . Here's an example -

```
<h5 class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="10s"></h5>
```

so i basically want to disable the class of "wow"

Comment: What have you already tried? Why not figure out whey the code doesn't work in Safari?

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to find a plugin that does work in Safari.

Comment: I agree with @BenM. jQuery supports Safari, so I recommend finding the real problem and not try to go around it with a hack.

Comment: Great way to make friends around here @MarcosPérezGude.

Comment: I need friends that uses the brain.  Thank you. Note that the OP can solve his issue with my answer, even you don't like it. First, read and document yourself. I no need tons of reputation if I don't know how to work

Comment: I am sorry for my comments, but my instance in stackoverflow is full of fast-finger-downvotes that makes downvotes without thinking first in the solution. And today is not my best day. You are not guilty of this, because of this I'm so sorry.

Comment: Actually, if you read and actively checked, you'd have seen that I rescinded my downvote, edited your answer and improved it. Your comments do not reflect you in a good light, and simply calling everyone 'idiots' is not helping your cause.

Comment: Thank you, but is my fault and I assume 3 downvotes even in my correct answer. Sorry for this. I am not searching friends here, but I like to help other users.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pf0z1rbn/ ?

Comment: @urbz That triggers true in Chrome on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conditionizr](http://conditionizr.com/) to this purpose. It says to you what browser is rendering in CSS and in JS.

Is as simple as include the script and execute the following JS:

```
conditionizr.on('safari', function () {
    $('.wow').removeClass('wow');
});
```

Comment: That doesn't remove the class for Safari users. It just hides the element in Safari.

Comment: @BenM is an example. You can make anything with this types of plugins. Conditionizr and Modernizr are being used for this purposes by google, microsoft, apple.... Are you smarter than them? If you view the documentation, you can use it with javascript and make anything that you like. Your fast-finger-downvote sucks.

Comment: Providing a link to something and saying 'this will work', and then giving a completely unrelated code sample is not an answer.

Comment: First of all, you need to stop taking things personally. StackOverflow is all about providing quality answers. And secondly, no, your edit is no better; it simply removes the elements with a class of `wow` from the DOM, which is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Sorry for calling you fast-finger-downvote and troll. But you haven't reason.

Comment: thanks for the answers lads . agreed that the best thing to do is work out why the problem occurs in safari but i'm having trouble with that . they are essentially css animations powered by a jquery library so are not essential . if i can't find the problem then removing the classes for safari would be a work around

Comment: My friend @BenM removes the css code, but you can use it like this `.safari .wow { color:red;} `.  Do the stuff customized by browser

Comment: thanks for the replies . as per Bens advice i've resolved the problem with safari and no longer need to remove the class . as an aside i've noticed google fonts appear much lighter in safari . i've tried -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;  , -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; and -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; . however none of these have solved the problem . any ideas

Comment: We don't know what problem do you have. You are asking for `Is there a way to disable css classes applied to an element for specific browsers` and I answer you how to. But if your problem persists, please, be more specific, share more code, make a fiddle and explain better what is your problem and what is that you need. Thank you